# Imagick exception "unable to open image" when converting a CR2 or NEF

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I try to convert a .CR2 or .NEF file to jpg using imagik.

ImageMagik is installed on the server.
My code :

```
$im = new Imagick( 'canonRaw_test.CR2' );
$im->setImageFormat( 'jpg' );
$im->writeImage( 'canonRaw_test.jpg' );
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

It returns : 
    **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/var/tmp/magick-80620Kc-ZP09ux4Rc.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2658'**

The same code works perfectly with jpg or even .HDR file.

Note : the image file seems to be good. I tested with other .cr2 to be sure it's not a problem due to the file itself.

Any idear ?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to install `dcraw`. https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#crw

Comment: You may need to install `ufraw`.

Comment: All right. dcraw or ufraw ? Which is the best ?

Comment: Ok. I installed ufraw, but my problem is still there : the code of my question still returns the same error. 
Is there something to do to "link" ufraw and imagick ?

Comment: @PaxMaximinus Try `dcraw` now.

Comment: That's what I did, but I have the same problem.
I installed dcraw , everything seems to be ok. I restarted the server. But I still have the exception when I try my code.
Normally a simple dcraw install should cure the problem ??
Because I tried on my Mac with MAMP and on a CentoS 6 server with the same success.

Comment: I continue : dcraw is well installed. I tested `dcraw -i canonRaw_test.CR2` and it returns `canonRaw_test.CR2 is a Canon EOS 60D image.`

Comment: In command line Imagemagick, you need to preface your cr2 input file with `CR2:`. So try $im = new Imagick( 'CR2:canonRaw_test.CR2' );. I think on Windows you use draw and on Unix you use ufraw.

Comment: @fmw42 : I tried it, without success.

Comment: In Terminal, run `which dcraw` (or `which ufraw`) and get the correct, full path to it. Then ensure that the directory which contains it is in the PATH your PHP setup uses - which is likely **different** from the PATH your Terminal and shell use.

Comment: I sloved it. Thank all of you people.

Comment: To help others, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

All right, I solved it.

I had to install ufraw.
On CentOS :

```
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
yum install libjpeg-turbo dcraw perl-Image-ExifTool
yum install ufraw
```

then update the delegates.xml of imageMagick :

```
<delegate decode="dng:decode" command="&quot;ufraw-batch&quot; --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 &quot;--output=%u.png&quot; &quot;%i&quot;"/>
```

with the absolute path of ufraw-batch :

```
command="&quot;ufraw-batch&quot;
```

replaced by :

```
command="&quot;/usr/bin/ufraw-batch&quot;
```

To find this absolute path I used

```
locate ufraw-batch
```

In case it doesn't reveal the location, use :

```
echo $PATH
```

which will give you the folders where programs can be, and try an "ls" on each of them. You will find ufraw-batch and then its absolute path.

I spent 2 days to achieve that as I'm not used to playing with command lines. Hope it could help someone in the future.

Comment: On Lubuntu, just installing ufraw fixed the problem for me, `sudo apt-get install ufraw`, and then `convert img.cr2 img.jpeg`. Voila! Thanks.