# Imagick exception "unable to open image" when reading a image file with exitension arw

Tags: php, imagick

try to reading a .raw jpg using imagik.

ImageMagik is installed on the server. My code :

```
$path = '1.arw';
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImage($path);
```

that is work on window but not work on linux ,
it throw exception

```
Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open image '/tmp/magick-ksjjsfHJJhdfhd.ppm':
```

so I try to solve it by by the method [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958767/imagick-exception-unable-to-open-image-when-converting-a-cr2-or-nef),this method has a little well,because finally create a tmp file in /tmp dir ,but with png extesion not ppm extension,so how can i solve it ,thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have ARW in your coder.xml configuration file? i.e. `<coder magick="ARW" name="DNG"/>`